# cap command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capistrano

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.2 and I installed ruby & rails with rbenv.

I try to install capistrano with

```
gem install capistrano
```

> Successfully installed capistrano-2.13.5
>
> 1 gem installed
>
> Installing ri documentation for capistrano-2.13.5...
>
> Installing RDoc documentation for capistrano-2.13.5...

Everytime I try to install with code, It says "1 gem installed".

---

But, If I write

```
capify .
```

I'm getting error like this.

> zsh: command not found: capify

---

My $PATH

> /Users/lutfidemirci/.rbenv/bin:/Users/lutfidemirci/.rbenv/shims:/Users/lutfidemirci/.rbenv/shims:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/Users/lutfidemirci/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `rbenv rehash` to make rbenv generate a binary shim for capistrano.

Answer (score 8):

If someone's using Capistrano 3.0.0 or higher should use:

```
cap install
```

instead of deprecated:

```
capify .
```