# Unable to deploy using Capistrano - 'Cap: command not found'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my app to the server using capistrano but getting this error message:

```
deployer@test:~$ cap production deploy
-bash: cap: command not found
```

How do I fix it?

When I run whereis cap, I get this:

```
Faisals-Air:transfercorp fkhalid2008$ whereis cap
/usr/bin/cap
```

Comment: Those are two different shells, care to give a little more detail on your environments? Are you trying to deploy from your test server?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337516/cap-command-not-found

Comment: i have 4 environments....
a) development - your local env starts by default when you hit "rails s"
b) test - test env starts when you run automated tests;
c) staging - test.transfercorp.co.uk
d) production - live site

Comment: @hikmatyar Okay. Don't deploy from your test server/environment.

Comment: ok, but i can't even get cap staging deploy to work. i get the error message 'cap: command not found'

Comment: Try running `cap` where you successfully ran `whereis cap` (but in the directory your project is in) - you shouldn't experience issues if you run it from the correct bash prompt. Like I said originally, you're running `cap` in one environment, then locating it in a completely separate shell.

Comment: If i try running cap, I get this: Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`, where production is a stage you have defined.

Comment: You didn't `cd` to the project directory...